# Windows Phone 8 ListBox MVVM scrolling issue

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am writing a Windows Phone application when in one of the pages I am displaying `ListBox` which items.

My goal is to scroll `ListBox` automatically to down when new item is added but I cant achieve that.

I have read many examples with behaviours and triggers binding but I can't do that.

I can't find a valid `Event` for me where I can simply get the `ScrollViewer` of `ListBox` and go with my method (this is not really need to be like that):

```
var childscount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(MyListBox);
for (int i = 0; i < childscount; i++)
{
    if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(MyListBox, i) is ScrollViewer)
    {
        var sv = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ic, i) as ScrollViewer;
        sv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(sv.ScrollableHeight);
        break;
    }
}
```

If I had to write this in codebehind there would be no problem because I can raise the method when adding new item to collection.

Problem is I am trying to do it in MVVM.

Comment: I dont see the usefulness of this idea at all, why do you wanna move this code to your view model. The best way is to make a new UI Component by inheriting the ListBox control and redefining the behavior after adding new items. If you really wanna do it in the view model, youll have to make your page visible to your UI which breaks the MVVM design pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting my solution if enyone will be searching for example:

```
public class ItemsControlBehavior : Behavior<ListBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged -= ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged;
    }

    private void ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged(object sender,
        System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AssociatedObject.Items.Any())
        {
            AssociatedObject.ScrollIntoView(AssociatedObject.Items[AssociatedObject.Items.Count - 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still I am having an issue when I open the page with the ListBox again the event of ItemsChanged is raised so many times as I open the Page... I am navigating between pages with method App.RootFrame.Navigate()

Answer (score 0):

You need to use => listbox.ScrollIntoView(listbox.Items[listbox.Items.Count - 1]); But now you need set the selectedItem to the last and use SelectionChanged for use this methode always when you add an item.

```
SelectedItem = yourList[yourList.lenght - 1]
SelectionChanged Event => listbox.ScrollIntoView(listbox.Items[listbox.Items.Count - 1]);
listBox.clearSelection
```

I think it still work.